# ISO a good way to let a function accept a mix of supplied arguments, arguments from a list, and defaults

Tags: r, parameter-passing, metaprogramming, default-value

I would like to have a function accept arguments in the usual R way, most of which will have defaults. But I would also like it to accept a list of named arguments corresponding to some or some or all of the formals. Finally, I would like arguments supplied to the function directly, and not through the list, to override the list arguments where they conflict.

I could do this with a bunch of nested if-statements. But I have a feeling there is some elegant, concise, R-ish programming-on-the-language solution -- probably multiple such solutions -- and I would like to learn to use them. To show the kind of solution I am looking for:

```
> arg_lst <- list(x=0, y=1)
> fn <- function(a_list = NULL, x=2, y=3, z=5, ...){
   <missing code>
   print(c(x, y, z))
  }

> fn(a_list = arg_list, y=7)
```

Desired output:

```
x  y  z
0  7  5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like a lot about @jdobres's approach, but I don't like the use of `assign` and the potential scoping breaks.

I also don't like the premise, that a function should be written in a special way for this to work. Wouldn't it be better to write a wrapper, much like `do.call`, to work this way with any function? Here is that approach:

*Edit: solution based off of `purrr::invoke`*

Thinking a bit more about this, `purrr::invoke` almost get's there - but it will result in an error if a list argument is also passed to `...`. But we can make slight modifications to the code and get a working version more concisely. This version seems more robust.

```
library(purrr)
h_invoke = function (.f, .x = NULL, ..., .env = NULL) {
    .env <- .env %||% parent.frame()
    args <- c(list(...), as.list(.x))  # switch order so ... is first
    args = args[!duplicated(names(args))] # remove duplicates
    do.call(.f, args, envir = .env)
}

h_invoke(fn, arg_list, y = 7)
# [1] 0 7 5
```

---

Original version borrowing heavily from jdobres's code:

```
hierarchical_do_call = function(f, a_list = NULL, ...){
   formal_args = formals() # get the function's defined inputs and defaults
   formal_args[names(formal_args) %in% c('f', 'a_list', '...')] = NULL # remove these two from formals
   supplied_args <- as.list(match.call())[-1] # get the supplied arguments
   supplied_args[c('f', 'a_list')] = NULL # ...but remove the argument list and the function
   a_list[names(supplied_args)] = supplied_args
   do.call(what = f, args = a_list)
}

fn = function(x=2, y=3, z=5) {
  print(c(x, y, z))
}

arg_list <- list(x=0, y=1)
hierarchical_do_call(f = fn, a_list = arg_list, y=7)
# x  y  z
# 0  7  5
```

---

Comment: Very nice! My own answer felt a bit ugly to me. Slapping my forehead for not realizing it’d be more sane to do it your way, with the function passed as an arg in a wrapper.

Comment: When I look at code from a first-rate programmer, this is what I see: clean, simple, abstract. <sigh> Well, I'll never write poetry like ee cummings, either. At least I have the eye to appreciate it when I see it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how "elegant" this is, but here's my best attempt to satisfy the OP's requirements. The if/else logic is actually pretty straightforward (no nesting needed, per se). The real work is in collecting and sanitizing the three different input types (formal defaults, the list object, and any supplied arguments).

```
fn <- function(a_list = NULL, x = 2, y = 3, z = 5, ...) {

  formal_args <- formals() # get the function's defined inputs and defaults
  formal_args[names(formal_args) %in% c('a_list', '...')] <- NULL # remove these two from formals
  supplied_args <- as.list(match.call())[-1] # get the supplied arguments
  supplied_args['a_list'] <- NULL # ...but remove the argument list

  # for each uniquely named item among the 3 inputs (argument list, defaults, and supplied args):
  for (i in unique(c(names(a_list), names(formal_args), names(supplied_args)))) {
    if (!is.null(supplied_args[[i]])) {
      assign(i, supplied_args[[i]])
    } else if (!is.null(a_list[[i]])) {
      assign(i, a_list[[i]])
    }
  }

    print(c(x, y, z))
}

arg_lst <- list(x = 0, y = 1)
fn(a_list = arg_lst, y=7)

[1] 0 7 5
```

With a little more digging into R's meta-programming functions, it's actually possible to pack this hierarchical assignment into its own function, which is designed to operate on the function environment that called it. This makes it easier to reuse this functionality, but it definitely breaks scope and should be considered dangerous.

The "hierarchical assignment" function, mostly the same as before:

```
hierarchical_assign <- function(a_list) {

  formal_args <- formals(sys.function(-1)) # get the function's defined inputs and defaults
  formal_args[names(formal_args) %in% c('a_list', '...')] <- NULL # remove these two from formals
  supplied_args <- as.list(match.call(sys.function(-1), sys.call(-1)))[-1] # get the supplied arguments
  supplied_args['a_list'] <- NULL # ...but remove the argument list

  # for each uniquely named item among the 3 inputs (argument list, defaults, and supplied args):
  for (i in unique(c(names(a_list), names(formal_args), names(supplied_args)))) {
    if (!is.null(supplied_args[[i]])) {
      assign(i, supplied_args[[i]], envir = parent.frame())
    } else if (!is.null(a_list[[i]])) {
      assign(i, a_list[[i]], envir = parent.frame())
    }
  }
}
```

And the usage. Note that the the calling function must have an argument named `a_list`, and it must be passed to `hierarchical_assign`.

```
fn <- function(a_list = NULL, x = 2, y = 3, z = 5, ...) {

    hierarchical_assign(a_list)

    print(c(x, y, z))
}

[1] 0 7 5
```

Comment: Nice answer! I borrowed a lot of code in my answer, hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

I think `do.call()` does exactly what you want. It accepts a function and a list as arguments, the list being arguments for the functions. I think you will need a wrapper function to create this behavior of "overwriting defaults"

Comment: I think do.cal does it so long as I write arguments in both the interior and the exterior function. But the whole reason for the hierarchical structure where the list dominates the defaults but is dominated by individual arguments is so that you don't have to reach inside the function. I don't see an obvious way to do this at the outer level with either a wrapper to do.call or something in the wrapped function or both. I'm not saying it is impossible -- just that I don't know how to do it.